# Vue.js: Cannot run project; jsconfig.json file is empty?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I am trying my hand at a Vue.js project. I am using VS Code running as administrator. I am following the quickstart guide here: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application

I have Node version 6.14.13 installed. Typing `npm --version` confirms this.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. `npm init vue@latest`: I selected 'no' for all the options. I named my project 'my-vue-project'
2. I received instructions to run:

```
   > cd <my-vue-project>
   > npm install
   > npm run dev
```

3. `cd .\my-vue-project\` project was successfully created, so no problems moving to the project directory.
4. `npm install` I received some notices about package funding, but nothing that indicates a serious error has occured
5. `npm run dev` This is where I am now stuck. I receive the following error:

```
X [ERROR] Unexpected end of file in JSON

    ../jsconfig.json:1:0:
      1 │ 
        ╵ ^

failed to load config from E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
../jsconfig.json:1:0: ERROR: Unexpected end of file in JSON
    at failureErrorWithLog (E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1604:15)
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1056:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1476:61)
    at buildResponseToResult (E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1054:7)
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1166:14
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:701:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:756:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:677:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-vue-project@0.0.0 dev: `vite`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-vue-project@0.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-03T20_29_53_000Z-debug.log
```

Here is the content of the log file it mentions in that last line:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle my-vue-project@0.0.0~predev: my-vue-project@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle my-vue-project@0.0.0~dev: my-vue-project@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-vue-project@0.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-vue-project@0.0.0~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\nmorr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\nmorr\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\nmorr\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\nmorr\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\nmorr\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
9 verbose lifecycle my-vue-project@0.0.0~dev: CWD: E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project
10 silly lifecycle my-vue-project@0.0.0~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vite' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-vue-project@0.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-vue-project@0.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: my-vue-project@0.0.0 dev: `vite`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-vue-project@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd E:\xampp\htdocs\my-vue-project
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.17.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-vue-project@0.0.0 dev: `vite`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-vue-project@0.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have looked at the jsconfig.json file and it is completely empty.

I do not know why this is or what I should put in there.

I am not fully versed in Node, so I am assuming it's something wrong on my end; the Vue quickstart guide has no troubleshooting steps for when `npm run dev` fails. I just don't know what it is that has gone wrong.

I am able to run the index.html page generated from `npm init vue@latest` using the VS Code Live Server plugin, however, I really would like to understand why `npm run dev` isn't working.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm` and `node` are related but will have different version numbers.  You can find out your Node version from running `node -v` in your terminal.

From searching [previous releases](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) I found that npm 6.14.13 is associated with Node 14

The Vue quick-start guide under pre-requisites states:

> Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) version 16.0 or higher

Retry making a new Vue app after upgrading your version of Node (latest LTS version is currently 18.14.2)

Comment: That's it! I had node 14 installed. Deleting the old node files and installing the latest version has it up and running.